# construct to be used in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, plsql, cursor, nested-loops

I have sample Data like:

Table empdata:

```
Name    Desig       Sal
-------------------------
john    staff       26000
sen     owner       50000
smith   assistant   10000
```

i want to print each of the columns like

```
Current field value is : John
Current field value is : staff
Current field value is : 26000
Current field value is : sen
Current field value is : owner
Current field value is : 50000.. and so on
```

I am able to use cursor to fetch the emp data:

```
cursor c1 is 
select name, desig, sal from empdata;
```

but i want to iterate over the columns too. I have shown 3 columns here, but there are atleast 30 columns in actual data, and i would like to print each of the field.
Please help.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Is it a homework/for-your-own-learning question? This sort of thing is typically something you wouldn't rely on the database to do in production code. Having said that, once you've got a row and you've fetched it into a record or individual variables, you can just use dbms_output.put_line to output the value of each column as you require. If you need more help than that, please update your question to provide the code you have generated so far and we can advise from there.

Comment: hi, the cursor is actually data from 4 tables combined. now for each column in that cursor, i have a sql stmt to be executed, which is dynamic, so basically im doing a execute immediate for each column of the cursor record. hope this helps to understand my question more.

Comment: For each column, or for all values in all columns returned by your query? If the latter, then that seems a very strange requirement indeed. What do these dynamic statements do, exactly? Why do they need to be run? And how are they dynamic? It would help us to help you if your question contained information relevant to the issue you're actually trying to solve!

Comment: it is for each of the column value returned. the table is not empdata. it is only for illustrative purposes. im sorry i cannot post what data im dealing with, but i just need to execute sql statement with each of the column value of the cursor. thats the requirement. wondering if varrays can resolve this problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but you need to extend your example (using your empdata) to accurately mimic what it is you're actually trying to do. Using dbms_output to display values is very different from running SQL statements. What kind of SQL statements? Why are they dynamic? What if you have the same value in different fields? Why do you need to run these queries?

Comment: say, im doing something like `select approved from approval_table where data = c1.name` in place of c1.name, i need to substitute c1.desig, c1.sal, and so on... and if approved, i do some action. u can ignore the cases where data is similar n stuff..

Comment: And what do you want to do with the information returned by these queries?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this kind basic code.

```
begin
 for i in (select * from emp where rownum < 5)
    Loop
     dbms_output.put_line('Current field value is: '||i.Emp_id);
     dbms_output.put_line('Current field value is: '||i.emp_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: hi, sorry im looking for somehting like for i in (id, name, sal) loop putline(i)..

Comment: @Anu That's what Vishnu has provided you with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're after something like:

```
select name,
       desig,
       sal,
       (select approved from approval_table apv1 where apv1.data = emp.name) name_aprvd,
       (select approved from approval_table apv2 where apv2.data = emp.desig) desig_aprvd,
       (select approved from approval_table apv3 where apv3.data = emp.sal) sal_aprvd
from   empdata emp;
```

Quite what you expect to do with the information once you've got it, I'm not sure. Maybe you return this as a cursor? Maybe you pass it into a procedure? I'm not sure, but hopefully you have enough information to sort out your requirement?